# Did Muslims celebrate the attack on 9/11 in New Jersey in 2001?

Tags: united-states, politics, 9-11, donald-trump

Donald Trump claimed this in November 2015:

> "I
>   watched in Jersey City, New Jersey, where thousands and thousands of
>   people were cheering as that building was coming down. Thousands of
>   people were cheering."<sub>[New York
>   Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/22/us/politics/donald-trump-syrian-muslims-surveillance.html)</sub>

He later specified:

> It did happen. I saw it. It was on television. I saw it. There were
>   people that were cheering on the other side of New Jersey, where you
>   have large Arab populations. They were cheering as the World Trade
>   Center came
>   down<sub>[factcheck.org](http://www.factcheck.org/2015/11/trump-carson-on-911-celebrations/)</sub>

The NYT article claims:

> [A] persistent Internet rumor of Muslims celebrating in Paterson,
>   N.J., was discounted by police officials at the time. A search of news
>   accounts from that period shows no reports of mass cheering in Jersey
>   City.<sub>[New York
>   Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/22/us/politics/donald-trump-syrian-muslims-surveillance.html)</sub>

And factcheck concludes:

> [T]here is no evidence of it, the celebrating was not on TV and did
>   not involve "thousands and thousands of
>   people."<sub>[factcheck.org](http://www.factcheck.org/2015/11/trump-carson-on-911-celebrations/)</sub>

However, a month later, other websites report differently. For example breitbart states:

> The DC Media has spent the last two weeks attempting to destroy Donald
>   Trump with lies. Outright lies, and they are doing so in order to
>   protect a 14 year-old cover up. Not only have eyewitnesses and
>   contemporaneous reports proven Donald Trump 100% correct about Muslims
>   celebrating 9/11,  a just-uncovered  local CBS News (WCBS-TV in New
>   York) report completely vindicates Trump’s claim of “thousands and
>   thousands” of Muslims celebrating the fall of the World Trade Center.
>   [...]
>   FACT: Donald Trump is now 100% vindicated.
>   <sub>[breitbart.com](http://www.breitbart.com/big-journalism/2015/12/02/trump-100-vindicated-cbs-reports-swarms-on-roofs-celebrating-911/)</sub>

They post a CBS report, but it doesn't seem to show recordings of thousands of people celebrating, nor does it seem to talk about thousands of Muslims celebrating.

The political insider claims:

> Now, Former New York Police Department Commissioner Bernard Kerik has
>   vindicated Trump in his claims, noting that there were many post-9/11
>   celebrations by NYC-area Muslims.
>
> As One American News reports, Trump was
>   right!<sub>[thepoliticalinsider.com](http://www.thepoliticalinsider.com/trumps-claims-about-muslims-after-911-confirmed-video/)</sub>

The video seems to mention some reports about celebrations, but doesn't mention if these reports were confirmed, or if they involved thousands of Muslims.

My questions are:

- Did thousands of Muslims celebrate the attack on 9/11 in New Jersey?
- Was video of this celebration broadcast on TV?
- In case neither is true, is there proof of celebrations that involved more than a handful of people somewhere in the US?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45380/discussion-on-question-by-tim-did-muslims-celebrate-the-attack-on-9-11-in-new-je).

Comment: What kind of answer would you accept, since you are already suspicious of major news sources and fact checkers?

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm not. My main issue was that the factchecks that I could find were published very shortly after Trumps claim, and were not updated afterwards. The claims from sites like breitbart that Trump was 100% right about everything were issued after these factchecks. I accepted the answer of rougon, because they also included updated factchecks.

Comment: @tim IIRC Breitbart have written that massive celebrations happened in arabic countries and noted in the very end of the article that those did not happen in New Jersey. I have read a whole lot of conservative sources and not a single one claimed that there were celebrations in New Jersey. A probable explanation is that Trump was fishing press (like he did before): yes celebrations did happen and yes they were islamic and questioning whether they happened in US means being tricked into Trump's agenda. (this does not answer your question of course)

Comment: Actually, a lot of people are brainwashed. Terrorists were young innocent children but they received wrong teachings and ideas from their societies. I live in the middle east where it is easy to come across those kinds of ideas. Without research or questioning, I would easily believe that some people celebrated 9/11, sadly. That's why I spent more than a year making this video like that for children: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lzCbJzuv3g

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This has been a widely debunked claim.  At best, it is based on second- and third-hand reports of people seeing some people on the rooftops that they assume were Muslims and were celebrating.

- [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/2015/11/22/donald-trump-cheering-911/) has a piece about it.

  > Donald Trump insisted he witnessed television footage "thousands" of Muslims in New Jersey "cheering" the 9/11 attacks, despite the fact that claim was long since debunked.

  The article discusses many attempts to track down the source of these rumours, which found nothing, and discusses some theories about where these rumours might have originated from. It ends with a discussion of a newspaper excerpt Trump pointed to on Twitter in 2015:

  > ...(originally published by the Washington Post on 18 September 2001) described individuals who "allegedly" celebrated the attacks on rooftops in Jersey City (indicating that the celebrations were rumored, not confirmed). Trump claimed to have seen "thousands and thousands" of individuals in New Jersey on television, footage that has long been cited in rumors but doesn't appear to exist and doesn't jibe with the material he cited. Finally, it's unlikely thousands of any group of people could physically congregate on a rooftop.
- [Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/nov/22/donald-trump/fact-checking-trumps-claim-thousands-new-jersey-ch/) has a piece about it.  They give it the "pants on
  fire" rating.

  > If thousands and thousands of people were celebrating the 9/11 attacks on American soil, many people beyond Trump would remember it. And in the 21st century, there would be video or visual evidence.
  >
  > Instead, all we found were a couple of news articles that described rumors of celebrations that were either debunked or unproven.
- [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2015/11/22/donald-trumps-outrageous-claim-that-thousands-of-new-jersey-muslims-celebrated-the-911-attacks/) has a (repeatedly updated) piece about it. 
  They give it "four Pinocchio's"

  > Trump says that he saw this with his own eyes on television and that it was well covered. But an extensive examination of news clips from that period turns up nothing.
  >
  > ...Neither can we find any examples of Trump previously talking about this. Here, for example, is [an article](http://pagesix.com/2001/09/18/build-soaring-memorial/) in the New York Post interviewing Trump just eight days after the attack; he makes no mention of having witnessed the alleged celebrations. And in a foreword for a book titled [“Where Were You On 9/11?,”](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0972284206) Trump makes no mention of this: “I was in my apartment in the Trump Tower [on the morning of Sept. 11, 2001]. I knew what was happening because I can see downtown to the Financial district.”

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45344/discussion-on-answer-by-rougon-did-muslims-celebrate-the-attack-on-9-11-in-new-j).

Comment: It would be more accurate to say "There is no evidence for the kind of video or event Trump describes" instead of saying "this has been *debunked*". To say that it has been debunked is to prove a negative (that the celebrations didn't happen) which would be nearly impossible. You can't **prove** that Trump didn't see what he claims he saw, but you can provide evidence that the event probably did not occur and that the video probably doesn't exist. Quite far from *debunked*.

Comment: @LCIII if you want to look at the chat, there is a lot of discussion of this point.

Comment: this answer reads more like a political hit piece against Donald Trump than an attempt to actually answer the question (which wasn't about Donald Trump at all).

Comment: more interestingly this answer does not add anything to the question, which is already citing a newspaper and a fact checker. This should really use superior sources.

Comment: @jwenting I don't see how one can address the claims themselves w/out addressing Trump making them as he is the source of the claim and one of the only people still making them.  Sklivvz: what do you consider a "superior source" in this case?  Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: @rougon I would consider changing the wording of the answer to something more neutral. The OP suggests that fact checking *after the heat of the moment* might be more objective. Another possibility is explaining why you think these sources are more reliable than the ones posted by the OP. Is it just a matter of number of sources? That would not be strong, because of course it's an argument by popularity, and you would also need to show they are actually *independent* sources. As for strictly stronger sources, I don't think you can find any at the moment, but a historical review is an example.

Comment: @rougon and the sources in this "answer" are hardly neutral. They're in fact known to be highly partisan in the current election cycle.

Comment: @Sklivvz I find the wording to be accurate, but if you think specific wording is not neutral, please let me know and I will edit.  I don't see a "heat of the moment" quote.  The OP included those quotes in an edit after I had posted my answer, so I don't feel the need to change my answer each time the question changes.  As you mention, there are not many other kinds of sources for an answer to this question.  I honestly do not know what other sources I could use.  I could critiqute a Breitbart article, but didn't feel like that was the kind of thing the OP was looking for.

Comment: @jwenting I think the sources are neutral, at least in regard to this issue.  Who "knows" them to be "highly partisan"?  And would you recommend any other "sources"?

Comment: @rougon let me check history, you are making a good point.

Comment: Donald Trump is a known liar, not just on small things, but on major, life-and-death issues, as long as it benefits him or validates his previous statements. Anything he says should be considered a lie until independently verified.

Answer (score 24):

The OP asks:

> 1. Did thousands of Muslims celebrate the attack on 9/11 in New Jersey?
> 2. Was video of this celebration broadcast on TV?
> 3. In case neither is true, is there proof of celebrations that involved more than a handful of people somewhere in the US?

I think that there is an implicit question underlying this post which must be answered ( *intended by the OP or not* ), which is why do Trump and so many mainstream Americans believe that there were large scale celebrations by Muslims in the United States, in general, and in New Jersey specifically?

It may be that what Trump ( and many others ) remember are the widespread celebrations among Palestinian Muslims in Israel ( or by Muslims in other parts of the world ) which were widely reported in the media at the time.  Focusing specifically on the Palestinian celebrations, [Snopes debunks rumors that videos of these celebrations were forged](http://www.snopes.com/rumors/cnn.asp), and this [New York Post article](http://nypost.com/2015/12/03/the-video-of-revelers-cheering-911-that-no-one-got-to-see/?utm_campaign=SocialFlow&utm_source=NYPTwitter&utm_medium=SocialFlow) also discuss the issue:

> Here are the facts, all of which are matters of public record. On the afternoon of Sept. 11, 2001, thousands of jubilant Palestinians took to the streets, chanting “God is great,” firing automatic weapons and handing out sweets to passers-by. The largest demonstration took place in Nablus in the West Bank, where some **3,000 marchers danced and cheered** as guerrillas fired assault rifles and grenades into the air.

There are a few videos of the smaller celebrations that were published by Reuters and broadcast by various outlets like CNN, as noted by Snopes, however the videos of the larger celebrations which were filmed by the AP ( which acknowledges their existence ) were never broadcast, due to threats by Palestinian terrorist groups against it's reporters, as noted in the New York Post article.

I followed the link provided by the OP to the Breitbart site, and it appears there were at least a few **small** celebrations in various locations by American Muslims.  The [CBS news video](https://youtu.be/3auKMHkZJnQ?t=1m50s) the OP links to specifically mentions a small rooftop celebration in Jersey City reported by police, and [the Breitbart site](http://www.breitbart.com/big-journalism/2015/12/01/7-pieces-of-documentation-that-vindicate-trumps-claim-of-911-muslim-celebrations/) has been collecting what seem to be credible and specific reports of other **small** celebrations as reported for example by Dan Rather and former NYPD Commissioner Bernard Keirick.

It's quite likely that what Trump ( and many other people ) were remembering are the videos of the smaller celebrations by Muslims that took place ***outside*** the United States and were widely broadcast in the media at the time, plus the above listed credible reports of a handful of small celebrations by very small numbers of American Muslims, ***and are conflating them with the AP footage of the larger celebrations with thousands of people in Nablus, which were reported in the media at the time, but never broadcast***.

Comment: But how could he mistake Nablus streets for New Jersey rooftops ?

Comment: @SeriousSarah That is what people's minds do - we are notoriously bad at remembering exact facts. The same goes for the number of people he mentions.

Comment: If there is footage that you say exists but was never broadcast, then Trump can't have seen it.  Speculation about what he might have seen or might have thought he saw instead is irrelevant.

Comment: That's very true... :( Your answer should include a bit of proof that people didn't celebrate in New Jersey to fully answer the question asked.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan Footage **was** broadcast, as I clearly note, but only of various smaller celebrations, but not of the largest one in Nablus.

Comment: @SeriousSarah The OP had three specific questions at the end of his post.  The accepted answer only addresses the first quesiton, my answer addresses the other two, I'll edit that into my post.

Comment: You should look at the evidence the breitbart article gives.  There was not footage and the reportage was second-hand and unconfirmed (the articles mentioned above address that).  So he might be confused about what he saw, but he's made a very pointed political statements about thousands of Americans that is deplorable and has never offered a "I might have seen something else," so why speculate wildly about what he might have actually seen?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Actually, I don't think your answer answers my other two questions. I asked about other celebrations in the US (but outside of New Jersey). Video of smaller celebrations outside the US and video of larger celebrations outside the US that weren't actually broadcast don't really answer that. Evidence for the other various claimed celebrations across the US would be great (including their actual numbers), but I don't think that breitbart is very credible (I mean, they still claim that the report about a handful of people in NJ is proof that thousands celebrated in NJ).

Comment: You're not answering either the first question or the other two. Let me quote them: "Was video of **this** celebration broadcast on TV?" **This** celebration (the one in New Jersey) doesn't exist and didn't happen, so quite obviously it cannot have been broadcast. "In case neither is true, is there proof of celebrations that involved more than a handful of people **somewhere in the US**?" You're describing something in Israel. And your last paragraph saying that it's "quite likely" that Trump remembers when he said something else is pure speculation on your part.

Comment: @SeriousSarah you're talking about a man who says that he can build a wall for a ludicrously low price and then later increased the amount of dollars it would take. It's not a far stretch for him to look at Nablus and go, "Eh, yeah, that looks like Jersey".

Comment: Are you claiming that the celebrating in the streets in the middle east was never broadcast? Well how the heck did I see it then? Maybe it wasn't Nablus, all I can remember is somewhere in the middle east.  But I certainly remember seeing thousands celebrating in the streets.

Comment: I recall (memory being what it is) a video of **alleged** celebration (could've been other emotional response) by a few (10? 15?) **alleged** Muslims on a distant (New Jersey?) rooftop. I don't doubt that **some** Muslims celebrated. I also don't doubt that **some** non-Muslims celebrated the fall of Wall Street's iconic Twin Towers. Wall Street has many native American opponents, and some of them tend to be extreme. That's just in the nature of modern society.

Comment: @Dunk I clearly wrote that videos of various smaller celebrations **were** broadcast.

Comment: @jwenting please avoid racist comments

Comment: @Dunk -  so what?  Trump claimed that the celebrations happened IN NEW JERSEY.  Unless you care claiming that the Middle East is in New Jersey, or vice versa, you are trying to change the subject.

Comment: This may not directly answer the question, but I think it's a useful supplemental answer because it provides some context and explains how Trump's lie has taken hold - many people were shocked by the videos from Palestine at the time, and it's easy to mess with memories that are 15+ years old. Whatever your opinion about Trump, he's very good at muddying the waters and manipulating strong emotions.

Comment: I'd like to know how people who believe in these "celebrations" think it would have even been possible for a group of people to cheer and hoot -- with no fear of reprisals or  witnesses -- while everyone around them was screaming, crying and fleeing.